# Back to Default Git or gitignore settings on XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

Because me and my team started playing with the files that were included and ignored on the XCode Commit panel, our project has become very hard to manage on git. Since we added some libraries that we installed through cocoapods into git and uploaded them with the project, we have consistently gotten errors with files that don't show up on the user that pushed it, or other that show as missing for the user that made the pull.

To solve this, I want to take the most up-to-date branch, and reset git or the gitignore file in order to reupload to another origin from scratch, and hopefully have an easier time with our collaboration.

I haven't found a way to do so easily and safely. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to a standard gitignore file for your Xcode project, go to [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io) and enter **Xcode** in the search field. That will generate a standard gitignore file for Xcode projects.

Open up your existing gitignore file in a text editor. Replace the contents with the contents of the file gitignore.io created for you. Commit the gitignore file and push it to your remote repository. Now your team will be working with a standard gitignore file.